# populating kendo dropdownlist based on another dropdownlist selection

Tags: kendo-grid

I have 2 kendo dropdownlists in cshtml page. First has countries and based on the selection of countries cities are loading to the second dropdown. I am using ajax callback for this functionality. The ajax function is returning list of cities, but the dropdownbox is not loading with cities.

```
function countrydd_change()
{
  //ajax call function
}

function LoadCity(Countryid) {
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadCities", "Controllername")',
            data: { CountryId: Countryid },
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#citiesdd").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.read(data);
                result = "Success";
        },
        error: function (x, t, m) {
            result = "Failure"
        }
    });
    return result.toUpperCase();
}
```

Is there anything wrong with the above code. Or can anyone send me sample code for this.

Thanks in Advance,
Aradhya

Answer (score 1):

If your data format is correct then the correct method of adding data to datasource .`data` and not .`read`

```
 $("#citiesdd").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(data);
```